# Java I am getting an "Error: Could not find or load main class" for everything in cdm prompt Windows 7

Tags: java, eclipse, lucene

I wrote this question yesterday, but I copied the wrong output:

Yesterday I posted the output:

C:\Users\User5\Documents\eclipse\test>java Example.java
Error: Could not find or load main class Example

I tried that also, but it did not run for also the reasons in the various responses, that the run line should only be C:\Users\User5\Documents\eclipse\test>java Example

But, that is not the problem.  I just made a mistake in posting that, but

C:\Users\User5\Documents\eclipse\test>java Example
Error: Could not find or load main class Example

also occur.

I also cannot get any other files to run in the cmd prompt, although they all run in eclipse.

I am trying to run a java file in the cmd prompt in Windows 7

I get the error:

Error: Could not find or load main class

I actually just save a new simple file to check if there were problems with the package inside eclipse; this new file is saved just as:

C:\Users\User5\Documents\eclipse\test\Example.java

```
class Example {
    // A Java program begins with a call to main().
    public static void main(String args[]) {
    System.out.println("Test.");
    }
}
```

I changed the classpath for lucene's jar's recently, and I am not really sure if this is the problem.

There are many other threads about this issue, such as:

Could not find or load main class

but, there seem to be other concerns that solved their issues.

In this case, I have saved just a plain file in notepad, and while I can get the file to compile, and it seems to create the class file, it is still spitting this error back.

This is the dir, which seems to show that the class is there:

```
C:\Users\User5\Documents\eclipse\test>dir
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is 3E0D-3B82
 Directory of C:\Users\User5\Documents\eclipse\test

    12/07/2015  10:15 AM    <DIR>          .
    12/07/2015  10:15 AM    <DIR>          ..
    12/07/2015  10:04 AM               301 .classpath
    12/07/2015  10:04 AM               380 .project
    12/07/2015  10:04 AM    <DIR>          .settings
    12/07/2015  10:05 AM    <DIR>          bin
    12/07/2015  10:51 AM               428 Example.class
    12/07/2015  10:15 AM               162 Example.java
    12/07/2015  10:05 AM    <DIR>          src
                   4 File(s)          1,271 bytes
                   5 Dir(s)  10,000,461,824 bytes free
```

C:\Users\User5\Documents\eclipse\test>java Example.java
Error: Could not find or load main class Example

I was able to get

```
java -cp . Example
```

to run this file, but I cannot get other files to run.  I think I have changed something that is causing a problem when I was changing the CLASSPATH for lucene.

I still cannot get files from this dir to run:

```
C:\Users\User5\Documents\eclipse\test\src\test>dir
 Volume in drive C has no label. 
 Volume Serial Number is 3E0D-3B82

 Directory of C:\Users\User5\Documents\eclipse\test\src\test

12/08/2015  10:25 AM    <DIR>          .
12/08/2015  10:25 AM    <DIR>          ..
12/07/2015  11:56 AM               336 BlockDemo.java
12/07/2015  10:24 AM               433 Example.class
12/07/2015  11:28 AM               187 Example.java
12/07/2015  11:28 AM               351 Example2.java
12/07/2015  11:44 AM               661 Example3.java
12/07/2015  11:55 AM               273 ForDemo.java
12/07/2015  11:46 AM               433 GalToLit.java
12/07/2015  11:51 AM               690 IfDemo.java
12/08/2015  10:17 AM               296 KbIn.java
12/08/2015  10:25 AM             1,525 LogicalOpTable.class
12/08/2015  10:17 AM             1,035 LogicalOpTable.java
12/07/2015  11:15 AM               271 null.jpage
              12 File(s)          6,491 bytes
               2 Dir(s)   9,892,143,104 bytes free
```

C:\Users\User5\Documents\eclipse\test\src\test>java LogicalOpTable
Error: Could not find or load main class LogicalOpTable

C:\Users\User5\Documents\eclipse\test\src\test>java -cp . LogicalOpTable.java
Error: Could not find or load main class LogicalOpTable.java

C:\Users\User5\Documents\eclipse\test\src\test>java -cp . LogicalOpTable
Error: Could not find or load main class LogicalOpTable

Comment: Did you add Java as an environment variable?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
java -cp . Example
```

instead

```
java Example.java
```

Comment: Yeah that works; why does that make a difference.  I was able to run programs without the -cp before I started changing the CLASSPATH for lucene.

Comment: You've probably deleted the . from the classpath when you changed it to lucene. You can put many paths on the classpath separating them with ':'. For example: -cp .:lucene.jar

Comment: I am still having problems with other directories:

Comment: You should not post answers if you're still having problems. You have to edit your question.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably missing an ";." in your environment variable CLASSPATH variables then. While ; separates the different values, the period means "this directory".

Right click on Computer --> Properties --> Advanced system settings --> Environment Variables. Look for CLASSPATH in System Variables and add ;. at the end in value.

Maybe you should just look for a workaround to set up your java environment variables and completely set those up again.

PS. it is "String[] args"

Comment: Yeah that's probably what I'll get started on; thank you for your help!!